# Highcharts: Giving Series Update Animation Same Smoothness as Point Update Animation

Tags: highcharts

I have a highcharts scatter chart that will need to be updated with data on a button click.

Originally I was using update by point, because it has a very smooth animation where you see the points gliding across the chart to the new coordinates.  However, this doesn't really work for a larger data set.  For example, for 30 data points it works fine, but for 300 it has to loop through each point in the series, and that takes forever.

Doing it by series works just fine, but on update the new series just appear, giving the update a very clunky appearance.

I've tried setting redraw to false when doing update by point, and the redrawing the graph when all the points have updated, but there is still a huge lag for larger data sets.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to make the series update animation as smooth as the point update animation?  I've included a jfiddle that shows the animation difference between the two:

http://jsfiddle.net/3bt78p1k/1/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'scatter',
          zoomType: 'xy',
            animation: {
                duration: 1000
            }
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018],
            min: 2012,
            max: 2018
        },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Units Attempted'
        },
        min: 50,
        max:  100,
      },
        series: [{
            data: [[2012, 60], [2012, 62], [2012, 54], [2012, 70], [2012, 68]],
            name: 'Update by Series'
        }]

    });


    $('#update_series').click(function () {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        var newData = [[2013, 72], [2013, 77], [2013, 64], [2013, 72], [2013, 77]];
        chart.series[0].setData(newData);
    });

    var pointsArr = [72, 77, 64, 72, 77];
    $('#update_point').click(function () {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        $.each(chart.series[0].points, function(index, val) {
                this.update({x:2013, y:pointsArr[index]});
        })
    });

     $('#reset').click(function () {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
                var originalData = [[2012, 60], [2012, 62], [2012, 54], [2012, 70], [2012, 68]];
        chart.series[0].setData(originalData);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply an animation in `setData` method, points need to be matched by `x` position or `id` property. For example:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    ...,
    series: [{
        data: [
            {x: 2012, y: 60, id: 'one'},
            {x: 2012, y: 62, id: 'two'},
            {x: 2012, y: 54, id: 'three'},
            {x: 2012, y: 70, id: 'four'},
            {x: 2012, y: 68, id: 'five'}
        ],
        ...
    }]

});


$('#update_series').click(function() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    var newData = [
        {x: 2013, y: 72, id: 'one'},
        {x: 2013, y: 77, id: 'two'},
        {x: 2013, y: 64, id: 'three'},
        {x: 2013, y: 72, id: 'four'},
        {x: 2013, y: 77, id: 'five'}
    ];
    chart.series[0].setData(newData);
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0k1rqpa5/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData

Comment: I don't see any animation in the JSfiddle, just a jump. I think you forgot to set `redraw: true` when you called `setData()`

Comment: Hi @Trevor Gehman, The example works correctly for me. The `redraw` argument is set to `true` by default.

Comment: You're right it's not the `redraw` property. But if you click `Update by Point` first, then `Reset`, then `Update by Series` there is no longer an animation.

Comment: That's because of differet data in `originalData` array. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0k1rqpa5/1/